# Why doesn't work my-domain.com with www

Tags: ubuntu, web, apache2, vps

I installed and setupped drupal on my vps /digitalocean.OS: ubuntu 14.04.
I go to www.my-domain.com doesn't work but if i write my-domain.com its work correctly.Why? i wait your advice.
I use apache2.
its my drupal.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/drupal.conf

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin admin@my-domain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal/
   ServerName www.my-domain.com
   ServerAlias my-domain.com *.my-domain.com

   ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/my-domain.com-error_log
   CustomLog /var/log/apache2/my-domain.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

www is a sub domain that needs to be setup on your dns.

You need 3 records:
A - your-domain.com. - VPSIP
A - @ - VPSIP
CNAME - www - your-domain.com.

don't forget the dot at the end of the domain. It can take a while for this to update.

Answer (score 0):

Please verify and update Site URL in Drupal instance. Base URL in drupal would have to be updated as www.my-domain.com.